# Vitest - Test a conditionnal display

Tags: testing, next.js, vitest

I am just new with Vitest and test, and I try to test a conditionnal rendering. An image is display if the prop has an image and if there is no image a fallback with first letter of user is displayd.

```
type LoggedInButtonProps = {
  user: Session['user'];
};
export default function LoggedInButton(props: LoggedInButtonProps) {      
      return (  
            <Button variant="outline" size="sm">
            <Avatar className="mr-2 h-6 w-6">
              {props.user.image ? (
                <AvatarImage
                  src={props.user.image}
                  alt={props.user.name ?? 'user picture'}
                ></AvatarImage>
              ) : (
                <AvatarFallback>{props.user?.name?.[0]}</AvatarFallback>
              )}
            </Avatar>
            {props.user.name}
          </Button>
)
```

I tried a lot of thing and like that :

```
describe('LoggedInButton', async () => {
  test('user button has an image', async () => {
    console.log('props', user);
    await waitFor(async () => {
      await render(
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <LoggedInButton user={user} />
        </QueryClientProvider>
      );
      const userImage = screen.findByRole('img');

      console.log('image', await userImage);
      // expect(userImage).toHaveAttribute('src', user.image);
    });
  });
```

It will always, in all conigurations return me the testing DOM telling me there is span despite image :

```
  <body>
    <div>
      <button
      >
        <span
          class="relative flex shrink-0 overflow-hidden rounded-full mr-2 h-6 w-6"
        />
        Luc
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

But, in theory, I give him an image, so why  does he thinks there is not image and return the fallback?